# issue with starting selenium server on windows server 2019, encoding problem

Tags: python-3.x, selenium-webdriver, selenium-grid

What happened?
i've downloaded selenium-server-4.9.0.jar and run it on windows server 2019 using java -jar selenium-server-4.9.0.jar standalone

then tried this code:

```py
import requests
import json



url = "http://localhost:4444/wd/hub/session"

headers = {'Content-Type': 'application/json'}
payload = {
    "capabilities": {
        "firstMatch": [
            {
                "browserName": "chrome",
                "goog:chromeOptions": {
                    "args": ["--disable-extensions"]
                }
            }
        ]
    }
}

response = requests.post(url, headers=headers, data=json.dumps(payload))
print(response.text)
```

but when i try:

```py
headers = {'Content-Type': 'application/json; charset=utf-8'}
```

it works without issue

while i use

```
docker run -d -p 4444:4444 --name selenium selenium/standalone-chrome
```

it works without issue no matter if i use charset in headers or not, or even use ascii encoding in headers it works fine, but in my windows 2019 server, it only accepts utf-8 encoding and it must be used in headers
this is while i use the same system to send post request to both docker image and selenium server on my system

how can i run the selenium server that accepts multiple types of encodings? like the server on the docker image

windows server 2019
google chrome Version 112.0.5615.138
selenium-server-4.9.0
ChromeDriver 112.0.5615.49

how can i run the selenium server that accepts multiple types of encodings? like the server on the docker image